# Can I copy an entire database from an ODBC connection to a local file?

Tags: odbc

I have a working ODBC connection to an external database which will soon be shut down. I have already extracted all the information I think I'll need in the future, but I can't help but wonder if I can copy the entire database for storage locally.

I have already tried using MS Access with some success but I ran into at least two issues - the file size limit in Access is 2gb and the field limit for a table is 255 fields. Some of the largest tables didn't make it into the backup.

I tried searching for an open source solution with no success. Is there an easy way to copy the entire database to a local file in one shot?

Comment: How big is it?  SQL Server Express has a 10GB limit or there is the Developer version if you aren't using production data.  Both are [free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing).

Comment: I believe it's smaller than 10GB. I'll look into SQL Server Express. Thanks for the suggestion.